# How to show this rule works for whole numbers to the fifth power?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

Today I was shown a rule about natural numbers raised to the fifth power and an interesting method to generate them through the odd numbers.

> Start with $1 = 1^5$. Then skip the next $T_1 = 1$ odd numbers ($T_n$ being the $n^{th}$ triangular number). So we have skipped $3$. Next add the next $2^2=4$ consecutive odd numbers: $$5+7+9+11 = 32 = 2^5$$
>   Then skip the next $T_2 = 3$ odd numbers. So we skip $13,15,17$. Now we add the next $3^2 = 9$ odd numbers:
>   $$19+21+23+25+27+29+31+33+35=243 = 3^5$$ Then skip the next $T_3 = 6$ odd numbers. Adding the next $4^2$ odd numbers will result in $$49+51+53+55+57+59+61+63+65+67+69+71+73+75+77+79 = 1024=4^5$$
>   $$\vdots$$
>   This process can be continued to find any natural number $n$ raised to the fifth power.

$$ $$

I am wondering what makes this process work and if it can be shown that it works through an induction proof.

We can assume it works for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k^5$ can be represented by adding $k^2$ consecutive odd numbers. But these are very specific odd numbers, not just any list of consecutive ones. We would have already skipped the first $$\sum (T_{i-1}+i^2) =\frac16(k-1)(k)(k+1)+\frac16(k)(k+1)(2k+1)$$ $$=\frac12(k^2)(k+1)$$
odd numbers by the time we have figured out $k^5$. I'm not sure if I am even going in the right direction here, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of an arithmetic sequence is the number of terms time the *average* term, so if $k^5$ is the sum of $k^2$ consecutive odd numbers, then the *middle* of those numbers must be $k^3$.

The *first* number in the run is therefore $k^3-k^2+1$.

However, likewise, the *previous* sequence of odd numbers started at $(k-1)^3-(k-1)^2+1$ and ended at $(k-1)^3+(k-1)^2-1$. How many odd numbers do we then need to *skip* between the two sequences? Easy -- that is

$$ \frac{\bigl(k^3-k^2+1\bigr) - \bigl((k-1)^3+(k-1)^2-1\bigr)}{2} -1 $$

Multiply out the cubes and squares, collect like terms and cancel, and you get
$$ \frac{k(k-1)}2 $$
which is exactly how many odd numbers your rule told you to skip.

---

Even without doing the algebra in detail we can see that how many odd numbers to skip must be at worst a quadratic polynomial in $k$ (because the $k^3$ terms cancel out, so there are only lower degrees left). The fact that this polynomial happens to be the one that produces triangular numbers seems to be a coincidence, though.

Comment: I understand all the work you just listed and follow along everything just fine (+1). My last question is what let's us do all this work: How do we know that $k^5$ can be written as the sum of $k^2$ consecutive odd numbers in the first place? Or am I overlooking something in your answer where it answers this?

Comment: @WaveX: That is sort of implicit in the first sentence: $a$ can be written as the sum of $b$ consecutive odd/even numbers if and only if $b$ divides $a$ -- otherwise the midpoint of the sequence wouldn't be an integer (and neither would then the elements). The fact that the elements turn out always to be _odd_ in this case is mostly just another coincidence. (The elements are odd if $a/b$ and $b$ have the same parity, even if their parity is different).

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of this if and only if statement. That's really neat!

Comment: @WaveX: (With the caveat that you may need some of the consecutive odd/even numbers to be negative if $b > a/b$).